# Cannot display array data stored in App Delegate in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am working on a meme generator app. The meme generator is presented modally and is built into a tab bar view controller. The first tab displays all saved memes in a table view and the second is intended to display the saved memes in a collection view. The meme generator works as design and is saving generated memes to an array that is located in the App Delegate file (I know this is controversial, but it is a requirement of the exercise). I am attempting to set up the collection view and I am not able to get a reference to the meme object in the app delegate file and I don't understand why.

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var memes: [Meme]! {
        didSet {
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        memes = appDelegate.memes
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return memes.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.imageView.image = memes[indexPath].memedImage
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}
```

I based this code on the code used for my table view, which works as designed. That code is:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewMemesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var memes: [Meme]! {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        memes = appDelegate.memes
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return memes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        let meme = memes[indexPath.row]
        cell?.imageView?.image = meme.memedImage
        cell?.textLabel?.text = meme.topText
        return cell!
    }
}
```

How can I get a reference to the array data and display it inside of the collection view when the user saves a new meme? [Here](https://github.com/andrewTuzson/memeGenerator) is a link to the repo.

Comment: Basically AppDelegate is not the right place for sharing data. Use something like a singleton class or Core Data

Comment: Yea, I knew this was not best practice. This is how the exercise was written and it was a requirement.

Comment: Look for a better tutorial 

Comment: Yup, I am super close to being done with this one and then I am planning to move to another platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues, first you have to create a Custom CollectionViewCell:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var imageView:UIImageView!
}
```

remember to set the Custom Class for UICollectionViewCell inside the storyboard:

[image]

then when you dequeue the cell, be sure of `as! Cell`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.imageView.image = memes[indexPath.row].memedImage
    return cell
}
```

Then inside your `TabBarStoryboard.storyboard`, you must set `delegate` and `datasource` for your `CollectionViewController` (I checked your github, you didn't attach them).

Finally the result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I missed a lot of steps. When I make the following changes, I get hit with another error on line 37: Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'imageView'

Comment: Do all collection views need a custom cell object? This wasn't the case in tableviews and I am trying to wrap my head around the concept properly.

Comment: I was still missing a reference to "Cell." I must not be braining well today.